# My phone was in my pocket and it kept hitting my leg and typing in random numbers and locked my phone for over 160 days! Can anyone help me?

Tags: lumia

My phone got locked for over 280000 minutes which is over 160 days! I've tried turning it off and back on and taking the battery out and SIM card out. I can't figure out anything! Please help.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to hard reset your phone (This will remove all content from your phone!!!)

do the following to reset your phone:

Press and hold the Volume down Volume down button and Power  Power button buttons at the same time until you feel a vibration (about 10–15 seconds).

When you feel the vibration, immediately press and hold the Volume down Volume down button button until you see a large exclamation mark.

Once the exclamation mark appears, press the following four buttons in this order: Volume up Volume up button, Volume down Volume down button, Power Power button, Volume down Volume down button. Your phone should now reset and restart itself. (It might take a while for the reset to finish.)